# Getting null pointer exception along with a few other problems in a permutations program? (Java)

Tags: java, permutation

This is my code. I'm sure I'm just making a careless mistake here, but I procrastinated and I'm doing this in the middle of the night, so I'm a bit braindead. I'm trying to create an object that generates the permutations of a list. My teacher basically told us what each method is supposed to do so I tried to translate exactly what he said. When I try to test it with a main function though, I get a null pointer exception at lines 21, 22, and 35. 
These are the instructions given.

- (Base case> If I am a Permutations object of list length 0, do nothing, except to note that I should always return false when hasNext() is called.
- (Recursive case) Remove and remember the first element (c) from the list.
- Create and remember a new Permutations object (P) with the leftover list.
- Obtain and remember the first permutation (L) from this new object, or an empty list if it has none (because it is size 0).
- Initialize an index counter (i) to 0.
  Each time the next() method is called on a Permutations object, it should do the following:
- Return a copy of L with c inserted at position i. Increment i.
- Once i becomes too large, set L to P.next() and reset i to 0.
- If P has no next permutation, then this object is finished as well. hasNext() should return false from here on out.

  ```
              public class Permutations<E> //I know indentation is wrong here
              { // Couldn't get it to show as code unless it was like this
                  E c; // First Element
                  Permutations <E> P; // Are these the problem? 
                  List <E> L; // ?
                  int i;
                  boolean hasNext = true

              public Permutations(List<E> list)
              {
                  if(list.size() == 0)
                  {
                      hasNext = false;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      c = list.get(0);
                      list.remove(0);
                      P = new Permutations<E>(list); // Line 21
                      L = P.next(); // Line 22
                      i = 0;
                  }
              }
              public boolean hasNext()
              {
                  if(hasNext == false) return false;
                  else return true;
              }
              public List<E> next()
              {
                  if(hasNext())
                  {
                      L.add(i, c); // Line 35
                      ArrayList<E> newList = new ArrayList<E>();
                      for(int k=0; k<L.size(); k++)
                      {
                          newList.add(k, L.get(k));
                      }

                      i++;
                      if(i >= L.size())
                      {
                          L = P.next();
                          i = 0;
                      }
                      System.out.println(newList);
                      return newList;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      return L;
                  }
              }
          }
  ```

I realize the hasNext method seems really redundant, but we're supposed to have it in there. Also, it says when the next method is called in the object it's supposed to return the new copy of the list and then do everything else, but I'm confused about that because if it's returned first, how are the other parts of the method supposed to be reached? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also, this is the main test I tried to use:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(2);
        myList.add(3);
        Permutations<Integer> perm = new Permutations<Integer>(myList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you neglect to initialize `L` when `list.size() == 0`:

```
if(list.size() == 0)
{
    hasNext = false;
}
```

should be

```
if(list.size() == 0)
{
    hasNext = false;
    L = new ArrayList<E>();
}
```